# Jupyter Notebook showing blank page

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run `jupyter notebook` in the terminal for mac, and it just shows a blank page. All it has is the jupyter logo at the top. I'm on mac and used pip3 to install jupyter notebook.

I tried:

- Ctrl + Shift + R
- 127.0.0.1:8888/tree
- `jupyter notebook --port=8889`
- Downgrading the notebook version
- Clearing browsing history

Comment: What version of Python are you installing it on?

Comment: @Andrew I'm on 3.11.6

Comment: I'll go ahead try it through a new Pyenv environment. (I am also on macOS Sonoma)

Comment: Just tried it, it works on my end. Try reinstalling the `jupyter` package.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah I tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pip3, I used Anaconda Navigator and launched Jupyter Notebook from there and it started working.

Comment: I used [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) with `pyenv-virtualenv` and version 3.11.6, and it has worked.